# How would I generate a Figure 8 pattern (using recurrent neural networks) using a sine wave and triangular wave?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, data-science, recurrent-neural-network

I'm currently learning about Recurrent Neural Networks in my class and was assigned a homework to train a recurrent neural network. I've emailed my professor and my TA but none of them have replied since the break. I was wondering if you guys could help me understand what the input samples would be for the following statement:

"The purpose of this homework is to let you program the backpropagation through time (BPTT) algorithm to train recurrent networks. The problem is to learn by prediction a pattern in 2D space (two inputs) that will create a figure 8. Generate a sequence of samples in 2D space {x(i),y(i)} where x(i) is a triangular wave of amplitude 1/-1 and period 64 samples, while y(i) is a sinewave of amplitude 1 and period 32 samples. You can then create a periodic figure 8 easily that repeats itself. "

According to my understanding, x(i) would have samples in both x and y coordinates, but then the samples wouldn't be in 1 dimension -- they'd be in 2 dimensions. Similarly, y(i) would have 2-dimensional samples. So should I just take samples from the x-axis for the triangular wave and samples from the y-axis for the sine wave? that does not create the figure 8. Does anyone understand this statement better?

Answer (score 0):

For the {x} sample table, use function: [image: x(i)]

For the {y} sample table, use function: [image: y(i)]

With the 2D space {x,y}, you are generating samples using the iteration value [image: iteration value].

With both of the samples {x} and {y}, you and creating them on a 1D plane in regards to the value [image: iteration value] which is what relates both equations to the sample set on the 2D space {x,y}.